# Question on the bounded convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Bounded Convergence Theorem: Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a set of finite measure $E$. Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly pointwise bounded on $E$, that is, there is a number $M \geq 0$ for which $|f_n| \leq M$ on $E$, $\forall n$.

Then, if $\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$ pointwise on $E$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E f_n = \int_E f$.

I was wondering, would this theorem still hold if $m(E) < \infty$ but we drop the assumption that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded on $E$? I've been thinking about this awhile and feel like I've fallen into tunnel vision, I would appreciate a fresh perspective! Thanks!

Comment: The example is given just above the theorem in Royden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the classic counterexample is a sequence of triangles of greater and greater height and smaller and smaller width on the interval $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.

The sequence is 
$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
-n^2(x-1/n),&0\leq x\leq 1/n\\
0,& 1/n<x\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f_n(x)\to 0=f(x)$ pointwise, $m(E)=\ell([0,1])=1$, but $\int_0^1f_n(x)\mathrm dx=1/2\not\to 0=\int_0^1 f(x)$.

Note the functions are even continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true. Let a sequence of functions $f_n:(0,1)\to[0,\infty)$ be defined by

$$
f_n(x):=\begin{cases}
n,&x\in(0,1/n)\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

Then $\lambda((0,1))=1<\infty$ and $f_n\to f=0$ pointwise, but

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{(0,1)}f_n=1\neq\int_{(0,1)}f=0
$$

Comment: I understand this comment, and thank you for it. However, I'm confused, isn't your function uniformly pointwise bounded?

Comment: because my sequence isn't uniformly pointwise bounded, note that $n$ increases without bound

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $f_n(x)=nx^n$ on $(0,1).$